# Is Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(key, value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) thread-safe?

Tags: .net, winapi, environment-variables

The docs don't seem to say, so... anyone know if I need to add critical sections around this and all my environment variable reads if I'm doing it multi-threaded?

Hint: the reference source seems to be a straightforward shim to the native api in the cases I care about

```
 [DllImport(KERNEL32, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true, BestFitMapping=false)]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
        internal static extern bool SetEnvironmentVariable(string lpName, string lpValue);
```

Comment: I didn't find documentation, but I did write sample code that runs many tasks that mutate a 32,000 character environment variable value and didn't find any tearing of the result (e.g. any examples where results from two tasks both appear in the final value).

Comment: Lack of tearing doesn’t imply there are no visibility/ordering issues (reading/writing a reference type to a .NET field is also free of tearing). The ordering cannot be guaranteed larger-atomic without a synchronization primitive.. does it matter in context?

Comment: `SetEnvironmentVariable` in C# calls the WINAPI function `SetEnvironmentVariableW` (if adjusting the Processes Environment variables), which internally calls `RtlSetEnvironmentVariable` which is a small wrapper for `RtlSetEnvironmentVar` where it call `RtlEnterCriticalSection` on the `PEB->FastPebLock` if you are adjusting the Process's EnvironmentVariable.

Comment: You are responsible for multi-threaded synchronizing when the document doesn't state that it is thread-safe.